# How to get data from 2 mysql table

Tags: mysql, get

This is my CODE and I need data from 2 tables. First: `ps_customer(id_customer,firstname,lastname,email)` and second: `ps_adress(phone_mobile)`.

I got error:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /home/domain/public_html/k2.php on line 19

This is my code:

```
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","login","pass","dbNAME");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$gender = 6;

$sql = 
    "SELECT 
         ps_customer.id_customer, ps_customer.firstname, ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.email, ps_adress.phone_mobile
    FROM 
       ps_customer, ps_adress
    ps_customer.id_gender = '$gender' ";

    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">';
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$result["id_customer"].'</td>
                <td>'.$result["firstname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$result["lastname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$result["email"].'</td>
                <td>'.$result["phone_mobile"].'</td>
              </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

Comment: did you forget to put WHERE on the line `ps_customer.id_gender = '$gender' ";`

Comment: Plus you haven't specified how the two tables relate (INNER JOIN or OUTTER JOIN).  You need to specify which column between the two tables is where they match up .. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: actually he did specify by using a `,` a cross join will occur; however it's not likely the desired result.

Comment: You can't mix mysqli with mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to establish a relation between two tables like by having a key field and second you should JOIN the tables and then you can go on with your SELECT query.